# Removing b'' from string column in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame as taken from SDSS database. Example data is here.

[image: img]

I want to remove the character 'b' from `data['class']`. I tried

```
data['class'] = data['class'].replace("b','')
```

But I am not getting the result.

Comment: There **is no `b` character**

Comment: Please do not post screenshots. They are really not helping. Instead share data with the simple command: df.head().to_dict()  as an example. -1

Answer (score 32):

You're working with byte strings. You might consider `str.decode`:

```
data['class'] = data['class'].str.decode('utf-8')
```

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I smashed that up arrow for you.

Comment: @ScottBoston Lol, that made me chuckle. Thanks ;-)

Comment: Although true, the key here is the .str method for pd.series. The decode is just a normal string function. Anyway +1 :)

Comment: When smashing... try not to break it!

Comment: I do not like number 4 , so I make it to 5

Comment: Question: is their a way to apply this for all columns in a dataframe?

Comment: @Jonnyboi `df.apply` comes to mind

Answer (score 1):

Further explanation:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([b'123']) # create dataframe with b'' element
```

Now we can call

```
df[0].str.decode('utf-8') # returns a pd.series applying decode on str succesfully
df[0].decode('utf-8') # tries to decode the series and throws an error
```

Basically what you are doing with .str() is applying it for all elements. It could also be written like this:

```
df[0].apply(lambda x: x.decode('utf-8'))
```