# How to remove b' from values in dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, byte

I read my arff dataframe from here https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/00426/ like this:

```
from scipy.io import arff
import pandas as pd

data = arff.loadarff('Autism-Adult-Data.arff')
df = pd.DataFrame(data[0])

df.head()
```

But my dataframe has b' in all values in all columns:
[image]

How to remove it?

When i try this, it doesn't work as well:

```
from scipy.io import arff
import pandas as pd

data = arff.loadarff('Autism-Adult-Data.arff')
df = pd.DataFrame(data[0].str.decode('utf-8'))

df.head()
```

It says AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'str'
as you see .str.decode('utf-8') from [Removing b'' from string column in a pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46696679/removing-b-from-string-column-in-a-pandas-dataframe) didn't solve a problem

This doesn't work as well:

```
df.index = df.index.str.encode('utf-8')
```

A you see its both string and and numbers are bytes object

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/606191/convert-bytes-to-a-string

Comment: @ShimonCohen i don't think so

Comment: Hey bro, I'm having the same problem, I also realized we are working on same dataset :) Have you figured out the problem? I understand that you may have forgotten about this considering it's been some time, however I would ask if you could contact me and perhaps send me source code of anything you worked on this so far? My email: vanjavk@hotmail.com
Thank you! @french_fries

Answer (score 1):

I was looking at the same dataset and had a similar issue. I did find a workaround and am not sure if this post will be helpful? So rather than use the from scipy.io import arff, I used another library called `liac-arff`. So the code should be like

```
pip install liac-arff
```

Or whatever the pip command that works for your operating system or IDE, and then

```
import arff
import pandas as pd

data = arff.loads('Autism-Adult-Data.arff')
```

Data returns a dictionary. To find what columns that dictionary has, you do

```
data.keys()
```

and you will find that all arff files have the following keys

```
['description', 'relation', 'attributes', 'data']
```

Where `data` is the actual data and `attributes` has the column names and the unique values of those columns. So to get a data frame you need to do the following

```
colnames = []
for i in range(len(data['attributes'])):
  colnames.append(data['attributes'][i][0])

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data['data'])
df.columns = colnames
df.head()
```

So I went overboard here with all creating the dataframe and all but this returns a data frame with no issues with a b', and the key is using `import arff`.

So the GitHub for the library I used can be found [here](https://github.com/renatopp/liac-arff).

Answer (score 0):

Although Shimon shared an answer, you could also give this a try:

```
df.apply(lambda x: x.str.decode('utf8'))
```

Comment: AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values!

Comment: Shimons supposed answer doesn't work as well. actually y that answer is not about dataframe

Comment: what are the types of columns? are there any columns which are different from bytes?