# Pandas - Remove b"" from dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to remove all `b''` from my dataframes ( i.e. `b'stackoverflow'` to `stackoverflow`).

I came across [Removing b'' from string column in a pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46696679/removing-b-from-string-column-in-a-pandas-dataframe) however it just mentions doing this to one column.

Is there a way to apply this to all my columns in my dataframe?

Note: all my columns are `object` types.

I have tried:

```
df = df.astype(str)
df = df.str.decode('utf-8')
```

Comment: `df.applymap(lambda col: col.decode("utf-8"))`

Comment: hey, i'm getting error `AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'decode'`

Comment: Even after `df = df.astype(str)`?

Comment: sorry, I didnt have both in there. but now I get `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'`

Answer (score 2):

you can use the following:

```
df.apply(lambda x: x.str.decode('utf-8'))
```

Comment: thanks, still have the `b'stackoverflow'` though. I am using df= df.astype(str) before your line.

Comment: @Jonnyboi Can you provide some sample data?

Comment: @Jonnyboi just a sanity check, make sure to assign back or the changes won't be saved: `df = df.apply(...`

Comment: ok this works, but seems to convert everything into `NaN`.

Answer (score 2):

You must have mixed types of data in your df. First you need to select those "bytes" columns:

```py
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"a": [b"aa", b"ab"], "b": [b"ba", b"bb"], "c": [1.1, 1.2]})
>>> df
         a        b         c
  <object> <object> <float64>
0    b'aa'    b'ba'       1.1
1    b'ab'    b'bb'       1.2

>>> bytes_cols = df.applymap(lambda col: isinstance(col, bytes)).all(0)
>>> bytes_cols = df.columns[bytes_cols]
>>> bytes_cols
Index(['a', 'b'], dtype='object')
```

Then only convert those columns:

```py
>>> df.loc[:, bytes_cols] = df[bytes_cols].applymap(lambda col: col.decode("utf-8", errors="ignore"))
>>> df
         a        b         c
  <object> <object> <float64>
0       aa       ba       1.1
1       ab       bb       1.2
```

Comment: getting error `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 14: invalid start byte` on line `df.loc[:, bytes_cols] = df[bytes_cols].applymap(lambda col: col.decode("utf-8"))`

Comment: @Jonnyboi Then you have some characters that cannot be decoded into 'utf-8'. You may try: `col.decode("utf-8", errors='ignore')` (see my updated answer)

Comment: thanks it works! however there are a couple of columns it didnt work on - its columns that have blank records in some rows, including the row after the header.